# AngularJs $http not working with cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

first of all i am on developing a mobile app using ionic framework

in one factory i need to talk to a server side which is not in my domain (cross domain request)

i used this code and it never works for me

```
$http.get({
    url: 'http://test.wilson34.com/test.php',

    data: {
        "name": "peter"
    }
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    console.log('Success' + data);
    alert(data)
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    console.log('Status : ' + status);

});
```

but when do it using jQuery it works like charm

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://test.wilson34.com/test.php',

    data: {
        "name": "peter"
    }
}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    console.log('Success' + data);
    alert(data)
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    console.log('Status : ' + status);

});
```

please help i will not use jQuery in my project , any suggestions t do
 it using $http in angularJs

thanks in advance

Comment: try to set $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true in your angular config block

Comment: It will failed because you use jQuery's style, not Angular's style of doing AJAX.

Comment: http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$http.get('http://test.wilson34.com/test.php', {params: {name: 'peter'}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log('Success' + data);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log('Status : ' + status);
});
```

Params is an object with key, value pairs. In this case it evaluates to ?name=peter

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using the `$http` service in a wrong way. `$http()` is service, not a function you need to call the `get()` or `post()` method from this service:

```
$http.get('http://test.wilson34.com/test.php?name=peter').
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('Status : ' + status);
});
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: yes sure i know that and i was using $http.get but i just typed it wrong in my question thank for advice , but it not working

Answer (score 0):

Basically your syntax for `$http` is wrong.
Use it like a **service** is used in angular js and don't forget to use **$http as a parameter** to your method which hosts `$http` request

```
$http.get(URL)
.success(function(response) {
    console.log('success');
})
.error(function(response){
    console.log('error')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you all , [byrdr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783804/byrdr) said i was have to put the data in a param object that solved it

final code is :

```
$http({
            url : 'http://test.wilson34.com/test.php',
            type : 'GET',
            params : {
                'name' : encrypted
            }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            console.log('Success' + data);
            alert(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('Status : ' + status);
        });
```